# How to send data to a PHP script without BasicNameValuePair in Android development

Tags: java, php, android

I am learning Android using some online tutorials. All my java classes are good except for this one.

```html
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", user.userEmail));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", user.firstName));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", user.lastName));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "register.php");

            try{
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormaEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Here are all the imports

```html
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
```

[Screenshot of the error parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjxlb.png)

I have searched other questions related to this one but I would really want answer that is specifically for my case. Please advise.

Comment: HttpClient is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create A new Class. i.e RestClient.java

```
public class RestClient {


    private static String SERVICE_URL;

    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;
    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> headers;

    private int responseCode;
    private String message;

    private String response;

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public RestClient(String serviceMethod)
    {
        SERVICE_URL = serviceMethod;
        //this.serviceMethod = serviceMethod;
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public void AddParam(String name, String value)
    {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void AddHeader(String name, String value)
    {
        headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public String Execute(RequestMethod method) throws Exception
    {
        switch(method) {
            case GET:
            {
                //add parameters
                String combinedParams = "";
                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    combinedParams += "?";
                    for(NameValuePair p : params)
                    {
                        String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");
                        if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                        {
                            combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            combinedParams += paramString;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //SERVICE_URL +=serviceMethod;
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVICE_URL + combinedParams);

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                executeRequest(request, SERVICE_URL);
                break;
            }
            case POST:
            {
                //SERVICE_URL +=serviceMethod;
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(SERVICE_URL);

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
                }

                executeRequest(request, SERVICE_URL);
                break;
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse httpResponse;

        try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(request);
            responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                response = convertStreamToString(instream);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }
            SERVICE_URL+=SERVICE_URL;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }}
```

now in you AsyncTask you can call your Web services, that can be Post, Get etc. You can also easily add Header

example:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {

            RestClient client = new RestClient("your url goes here");
            client.AddParam("param1", "value1"));
            client.AddParam("param2", "value2"));
            client.AddHeader("Headername","Value");
            client.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);
            response = client.getResponse();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

For GET method just replace "client.Execute(RequestMethod.POST)" with "client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET)"

Comment: NameValuePair  is deprecated too

Answer (score 1):

`Httpclient` is Deprecated Use `HttpsURLConnection`

try to use `volley` in Android to send Data over the Network

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
                url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("name", "Androidhive");
                params.put("email", "abc@androidhive.info");
                params.put("password", "password123");

                return params;
            }

        };
```

[Android Volley Example](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Comment: NameValuePair  is deprecated too

Comment: @Mwas     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

Answer (score 1):

Httpclient is deprecated in the latest versions of android sdk 
use volley instead, refer here

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use most popular network library like retrofit or volley instead of using android HttpClient deprecated method. Retrofit is pretty simple to use. You can start it from here:

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en